# mbus to modbus protocol

Tags: raspbian, python-3, modbus

Im trying to convert mbus protocol to modbus IP protocol with a raspberry.

Im new on this, just doing bcs my boss asked. I´ve been searching on all google, but I found nothing. Any help would be helpful.

I´ve tried to read mbus bytes to convert, but it´s impossible.

Comment: "I´ve tried to read mbus bytes to convert" -- how did you do this? "but it´s impossible" -- what did you see and what did you expect to see?

Comment: A friend of mine told me that i could try reading the bytes and changing them to something about modbus @DmitryGrigoryev